# Insert HTML code with php and magic quote on

Tags: php, mysql, magic-quotes-gpc

I'm not an expert, so please don't laugh :)

I'm writing a simple script to adjust some pieces of HTML, and I need to store them inside my db.

I've magic quote on, I know that is deprecated but this is a local script.

When I try to insert my html string in the log I have errors for the single quote: '

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'input LAG
```

How can I fix this?

My php code is:

```
$string = stripslashes($pages[0]['description']);

for($j=1;$j<count($pages);$j++){ 

$string = $string.'<h3>'.stripaccenti($pages[$j]['name']).'</h3>'.stripslashes($pages[$j]['description']);

    } 

$string = stripslashes($string);
$db->query("UPDATE eve_articles SET body='{$string}'  WHERE id=".intval($oid));
```

This is the piece of code I'm trying to insert:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img width="400" height="266" alt="" src="http://www.dday.it/userFiles/FCK/products/219/IMG_1591 (Large).JPG" /></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: helvetica; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;"><br />
Passando al 200 Hz Samsung sfrutta a pieno il suo processore decisamente potente e offre un vero 200 Hz con 3 frame aggiunti ogni secondo. Una soluzione questa diversa da alcune soluzioni concorrenti che propongono il 200 Hz utilizzando per&ograve; tecniche di back scanning della retroilluminazione, tecniche che spesso e volentieri portano ad un abbassamento della luminosit&agrave; generale e non risolvono pi&ugrave; di tanto i problemi di Blurring. <strong>Samsung implementa il 200 Hz in modo poi personalizzabile, un grande vantaggio per chi vuole scegliere se minimizzare Blur o Judder</strong>. Chi ama cos&igrave; l&rsquo;effetto &ldquo;microscatto cinematografico&rdquo; ma vuole ugualmente beneficiare dei frame aggiunti per dare un po&rsquo; pi&ugrave; di risoluzione all&rsquo;immagine in movimento pu&ograve; farlo. <br />
<br />
Ottimo il processore video, realizzato tutto via software e inserito nella piattaforma: oltre a passare ogni tipo di test di deinterlacing integra anche una serie di tecnologie nuove: <strong>ARRT (Automatic Resolution Recovery Technology) e DCEC (Digital conversion error correction).</strong> La prima agisce in modo simile al sistema Resolution+ di Toshiba: analizza il contenuto e riconosce se si tratta di SD o HD, informazione fondamentale per il filtro di sharpening. Dopo aver riconosciuto il tipo di materiale applica una sorta di maschera di contrasto fine se si tratta di HD e pi&ugrave; blanda se il materiale &egrave; SD per migliorare il dettaglio fine dell&rsquo;immagine.<strong> Il secondo &egrave; molto pi&ugrave; interessante: &egrave; infatti un filtro che corregge gli errori di upscaling delle sorgenti esterne o dei broadcaster: riesce persino a ridurre piccoli problemi di combing e le scalettature</strong>. Il sistema integra anche un&rsquo;ottima correzione del rumore del video composito: se qualcuno ha pensato di inviare al TV un video composito upscalato a 1080p il processore se ne accorge e riesce comunque a togliere quel fastidioso rumore video sui colori (dot crawl). Ovviamente non pu&ograve; fare miracoli.<br />
<br />
Passando invece alla visione vera e propria integriamo quanto abbiamo detto nella prova con le informazioni di calibrazione. <strong>Il TV &egrave; quasi come una moto da corsa: per raggiungere ottime prestazioni si pu&ograve; lavorare su strade diverse</strong>. Si pu&ograve; infatti intervenire sul risparmio energia che abbassa il livello del nero ma anche sulla retroilluminazione e i vari filtri digitali, ma senza eccedere.</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: helvetica; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;">Noi abbiamo preferito tenere spento il risparmio energia e tutti i filtri portando la retroilluminazione a 4, il contrasto a 75 e il gamma a 1. Abbiamo poi regolato leggermente i primari e i secondari ma senza fare eccessivi stravolgimenti. Il contrasto misurato del TV &egrave; buono: <strong>871:1 utilizzando la scacchiera ANSI e 3976:1 utilizzando il metodo on/off</strong>. Questo con il TV perfettamente calibrato e senza dettagli affogati. Si pu&ograve; fare di pi&ugrave;?&nbsp;Si pu&ograve; portare il livello del nero vicino allo zero? Si pu&ograve; portare il contrasto on/off a 50.000:1. Si, ci abbiamo provato e ci si riesce: il TV riesce a tirare fuori numeri da &quot;favola&quot; se si esagera con i valori, ma a rimetterci &egrave; solo la visione, con poca dinamica e dettagli in basso inesistenti.<br />
</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: helvetica; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;">Che dire poi dell'input LAG? <strong>Abbiamo misurato il ritardo del segnale sull'ingresso HDMI 1 utilizzando un notebook in modalit&agrave; clone a abbiamo registrato un ritardo di circa 160 ms in modalit&agrave; film e con 200 Hz attivato e un ritardo di 56 ms in modalit&agrave; game.</strong> Comunque abbastanza alto.</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">L'<span style="font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: helvetica; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;">uniformit&agrave; &egrave; molto buona, con uno scarto del 5% circa sul pannello comunque tollerabile e praticamente invisibile.</span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: helvetica; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;">NB: l'assenza dei grafici di misura non &egrave; una dimenticanza. Stiamo valutando infatti cosa inserire anche per i prossimi TV. La scelta pi&ugrave; logica a nostra parere sarebbe quella di inserire la misura del TV in modalit&agrave;</span> &quot;film / movie&quot; con le eventuali regolazioni che tutti possono fare con un disco di test, come luminosit&agrave; e contr<span style="font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: helvetica; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;">asto. <strong>Ci sembra poco &quot;logico&quot; aggiungere grafici con gamut perfetti e punti di bianco perfetti se quelli sono ottenuti sul nostro esemplare e con l'ausilio di uno strumento.</strong> Chi possiede tale strumento pu&ograve; raggiungere tali risultati da solo, mentre pu&ograve; essere interessante vedere se il TV nei profili di fabbrica &egrave; buono oppure no. Ci afficiamo comunque ai vostri giudizi, ed eventualmente aggiungiamo i grafici anche su questa prova. </span></p>
<p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Can you show more of the code please? Like the HTML piece and php script :)

Comment: Did you try mysql_real_escape_string() ?

Comment: Or better, use MySQLi and [prepared statement and variable binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even if you don't have to worry about security, this still does you some good.

Comment: @SahinYanlık, post your comment as an answer. Roberto, check that answer. That way the question will be properly closed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try mysql_real_escape_string() ?